# django cms - static_placeholder show in all websites

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am writing a page which is multilingual. I am using i18n in urls.py so a page's url for german language looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/
```

english:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/
```

etc etc.

I have defined some `static_placeholder`s in templates. and I filled them with some plugins. I did this first when i was in `/de/` startpage. Once I switched to `/en/`, all those `static_placeholder` are empty again.

how is it possible to make them work for all languages?

Comment: Have you tried adding translated versions of your plugins on a /en/ version of your page?